# ls version number sorting Mac OS X

Tags: macos, sorting, ls, version

Is there an equivalent to `ls -v` in Mac OS X that will do version number sorting?

In Mac OS X, `ls -v` does NOT do version number sorting, but the Finder seems to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default `ls` in OS X does not have version sort capabilities. This is a feature of GNU `ls`, which comes with most Linuxes, but does not ship with OS X. You can install GNU `ls` through the [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/) package.

---

The easiest way of getting it on a Mac is to install a package manager like [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation)  or [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) and install coreutils through it.

So, for example, install Homebrew:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"
```

Wait a bit, read the installation instructions. Then, install coreutils:

```
brew install coreutils
```

This will add all the GNU coreutils with the `g` prefix, so for example, you will be able to use `gls` instead of `ls`, which now offers version sort.

---

To override the default `ls` behavior (and those of other builtins), you can add this line to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
source /usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.12/aliases
```

Note that this might affect other programs that rely upon the BSD version. If you just want to alias `ls`, use the following instead:

```
alias ls="$brew_prefix/bin/gls"
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.islamadel.com/en/notes/6-computer/37-sort-version-number-mac

bash script for sorting version numbers correctly on mac terminal